# How to convert RDD[List[String]] to RDD[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have scenario in spark-scala where i need to convert `RDD[List[String]]` to `RDD[String]`.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 9):

use the flatMap (`rdd.flatMap(x => x)`) operation on the rdd.

```
scala> rdd.flatMap(x => x)
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at flatMap at <console>:27

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(List("1","2","3"), List("4", "5", "6")))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[String]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[3] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val result = rdd.flatMap(x => x)
result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[6] at flatMap at <console>:26

scala> result.collect()
res7: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

filter for messages with **ERROR** and creating of String using `BidError` case class as requested in the comment as shown below.

```
result.filter(_.contains("ERROR")).map(BidError("2017-06-09",_).toString)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.... here there is one more issue, I need to filter the List of Strings , if string contains "ERROR" , if so I need to use below case class ///case class BidError(date: String, errorMessage: String) {

  override def toString: String = s"$date,$errorMessage"
}  and return this toString i.e. RDD[string]...thank you so much for your prompt reply

Comment: @user3252097 how do I construct the BidError class? ie what should be the value of date?

Comment: @user3252097 If you update your question with sample data then it will help rogue-one to answer you in better way.

Comment: Thanks a lot rogue-one , you saved my day . you have given clue i did it.

Comment: @rogue-one , sir , i am all the time getting below kind of errors.    ......... type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Double)] required: Map[String,Double]    , how to handle these kind of errors.

Comment: case class BidItem(motelId: String, bidDate: String, loSa: String, price: Double)